# Laravel migration name is too long

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I am trying to migrate the whole Laravel application, When I write the code below I have some error.

```
    // Create table for associating permissions to users (Many To Many Polymorphic)
   Schema::create('permission_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('permission_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('user_type');
        $table->unsignedInteger('project_id')->nullable();. 
        $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unique(['user_id', 'permission_id', 'user_type', 'project_id']);
    });
```

The error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name 'permission_user_user_id_permission_id_user_type_project_id_unique' is too long (SQL: alter table `permission_user` add unique  `permission_user_user_id_permission_id_user_type_project_id_unique`(`user_id`, `permission_id`, `user_type`, `project_id`))`

When I remove the code above, everything works well. What is wrong? I do not find anything?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The laravel's way of generating a unique key is too long. You can override this by doing

```
$table->unique(['user_id', 'permission_id', 'user_type', 'project_id'], 'my_unique_ref');
```

Also, if the foreign keys are too long you can override the default name but providing a second parameter.

```
$table->foreign('permission_id', 'my_new_reference')->references('id')->on('permissions')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: I removed completely this line and there is the same error. What kind of reference i have to put?

Comment: I've updated my answer it looks as the unique name is too long. With regard to referencing, I would have some name which makes sense to your application. For example, 'permissions_unique'.